# how to choose Dialogs according to features selected in installshield 2010

Tags: installshield-2010

I want to create a single installer for some web applications. Each application is a component of a feature. For each component I have some Custom Dialogs wich I created for save some configurations like connection string. My question is how to navigate through this dialogs according the features I selected to install. I think I have to edit the behavior of buttons in the dialog but I don't know what I have to write in Event, Argument and Condition. I try to find some informations in InstallShield User Guide but it didn't help me.

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

Windows Installer doesn't really support conditioning dialogs based on selected features or components. Instead, you can use some custom controls which conditions both your features and the dialogs:

- organize your installer into features (one feature for each application)
- create a custom dialog which contains some checkboxes or buttons that represent the features which will be installed
- write a [custom action](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/msicustomaction.aspx) which modifies the feature states based on these custom controls (you can use [MsiSetFeatureState](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370387%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) function)
- use the same controls to condition your custom dialogs

Most controls have [installer properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) associated with them (they are like variables in code). You can use these properties in your custom action and to condition your dialogs. It's not simple, but it's doable.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Cosmin! I want you to know that I found the conditions for features selected, I have two links if somebody have the same problem: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368561(VS.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012(VS.85).aspx